# incremental nested looping if statement vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a piece of code to perform a nested `If` statement. Easy to nest in Excel but difficult in VBA.

I want to automate that nested `If` into code that can increment to a last row and change the range with each pass.
I have looked through the answers here but am stumped.

The Excel `If` is `=IF(C2 > 1.42, A2, IF(D2 > 1.42, B2, "FAIL"))`.

My VBA attempt thus far is:

```vb
Sub ResultData()
    If Range("C2").Value > 1.42 Then
       Range("E2") = Range("A2")

    ElseIf Range("D2").Value > 1.42 Then
        Range("E2") = Range("B2")

    Else: Range("E2") = "FAIL"

    End If
End Sub
```

Just want the code to run down the rows to the last row, in this case at row 53.

[image: Current data]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your question has already been answered, I thought I should focus a bit on the good practices you should adopt.

Also, since the `cells` method has been shown, I figured it might be useful to also show how to work with ranges instead.

The comments should guide you through the basic logic.

```
Option Explicit 'Always add this line. It prevents you from using a variable without having declared it.
Sub ResultData()
Dim wb As Workbook 'declare a workbook variable which can hold a workbook object
Dim sht As Worksheet 'declare a worksheet variable which can hold a worksheet object
Dim i As Long 'declare a variable that will hold the row index. This should always be of type Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'assign the workbook where your code is, to your workbook variable.
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("The name of your Worksheet") 'assign the worksheet where your data is, to your worksheet variable.

For i = 2 To 53 Step 1 'loop through rows 2 to 53
                                                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If sht.Range("C" & i).Value > 1.42 Then         'Refer to ranges and cells by using explicit references to the                  '
        sht.Range("E" & i) = sht.Range("A" & i)     'worksheets to which they belong. So, sht.range("A1") refers to cell A1 of sht. '
    ElseIf sht.Range("D" & i).Value > 1.42 Then     'You can dynamically refer to a range by concatenating the column's index letter'
        sht.Range("E" & i) = sht.Range("B" & i)     'with a dynamically changing variable which represents the row's index.         '
    Else                                            'So sht.Range("D" & "3") for example refrs to sht.Range("D3").                  '
        sht.Range("E" & i) = "FAIL"                 '                                                                               '
    End If                                          '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub ResultData()
  For i = 2 to 53
    If Cells(i, 3).Value > 1.42 Then
      Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    ElseIf Range("D2").Value > 1.42 Then
      Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Else
      Cells(i, 5).Value = "FAIL"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome dotNet I'll be studying this one for a while. Excellent and thanks.